# Amazon Pay Invalid Order Reference Id (InvalidOrderReferenceId).

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-pay

On the `sandbox mode`, code is working without any issue. When I switch to the live, it said `the OrderReferenceId P01-XXXXXXX-XXXXXXX is invalid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. I was set the `fronted widget environment to Live` but mistakenly `the backed it was set to sandbox`. So, the order was not place to amazon end and the error was throwing.